# Converting for loop from vb to c#

Tags: c#

I created a program to query game servers a while ago in vb.net. I'm using a reference created for querying valve servers. Anyway, this is the VB code. It works perfectly in VB.

```
For Each player As aQueryLib.aQueryLib.Player In Server.Players
    lstPlayers.AddItem(player.Name)
Next
```

I'm creating a new program in C# and but I can't for the life of me replicate the above for loop. It basically adds the players of the server to a list.

How would I perform this for loop in C# 2010?

Comment: Have you looked up loops in C#?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228598.aspx

Comment: or even gone to a vb -c# code converter like telerik?

Answer (score 6):

You could try something as simple as:

```
foreach(var player in Server.Players)
{
    lstPlayers.Add(player.Name);
}
```

or if you want to make use of LINQ:

```
var lstPlayers = Server.Players
                       .Select(player=>player.Name)
                       .ToList();
```

> In theory yes but i need to use aQueryLib.aQueryLib.Player otherwise I
>   can't pull the name of the player

**If** you are concerned about the `var` keyword, this is just syntactic sugar. We let the compiler to infer the type of the variable called player, without to be needed to specify which is the exact type of this variable. For further information about `var` please have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx).

Comment: In theory yes but i need to use aQueryLib.aQueryLib.Player otherwise I can't pull the name of the player.

Comment: @Patrick what do you mean in theory? What is the `Server.Players`? I suppose it's a collection of objects? What's the type of these objects? I assume that all they have a property called `Name`. If none of the above isn't true, then certainly my answer isn't a solution to your problem. However, this is what I can infer from your code. If you could provide more infomration, I would certainly become more helpful. Thanks

Comment: @Christos I think OP is under the impression that `var` is the same as `object` in your `foreach`.  Anyway +1

Comment: @Micky google the difference between `Explicit && Implicit` in regards to what the word `var` means.. also in the debugger if you declare a `var` like this `var myVar = new List<string>` for example and hover over the word `var` it  Implies the object type same as doing `List<string> myList = new List<string>()` hope this helps

Comment: @MethodMan I know that thanks but _Patrick_ didn't appear to, hence my comment.  Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(aQueryLib.aQueryLib.Player player in Server.Players) 
{
    lstPlayers.AddItem(player.Name);
}
```

Comment: thank you.  This is what I was looking to do.  I had it backwards.

Answer (score 0):

[This link](http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/vbnet_csharp_comparison.html) is a bit dated (it does not have all the latest language constructs), but I find it useful when I need to figure out how to do the opposite: express C# that I know in VB.NET that I mostly do not. In the case of your particular question, it equates the VB.NET:

```
'  Array or collection looping
Dim names As String() = {"Fred", "Sue", "Barney"} 
For Each s As String In names 
  Console.WriteLine(s) 
Next
```

with the C#:

```
// Array or collection looping
string[] names = {"Fred", "Sue", "Barney"};
foreach (string s in names)
  Console.WriteLine(s);
```